# how to write unit test cases in jasmine for this code?

Tags: karma-jasmine

```
private getTotalMinutesBetweenStartAndEnd(startTime: string, endTime: string): number {
    // get each time's hour and min values
    let [startHrs, startMins] = this.getHoursAndMinsFromTime(startTime);
    let [endHrs, endMins] = this.getHoursAndMinsFromTime(endTime);

    // time arithmetic (subtraction)
  
    if (endMins < startMins) {
      endHrs -= 1;
      endMins += 60;
    }
    let mins = endMins - startMins;
    let hrs = endHrs - startHrs;

    // this handles scenarios where the startTime > endTime

    if (hrs < 0) {
      hrs += 24;
    }

    return hrs * 60 + mins;
  }
```

Comment: please help me if any one will able to write it please

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.